# Change background color of control regardless if mouse is over a child control

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseover, windows-forms-designer, mousemove

I am making a custom control, the idea is that when mouse is over the control, the background color is different and when mouse is not longer over the control then return to the original color.

One problem is when mouse is over a child control nothing happens

I've tried assigning a common mouseover event handler for all children controls, but anyways when the mouse moves fast nothing happens.

I want a behavior similar to button control that no matter how fast the mouse is moving, the background color seems to change with no problem

Comment: show us your code so far, and where you are stuck so we can have a look at the problem

Comment: I am not sure where you are getting a `MouseOver` event. In addition, using the `MouseMove` event seems like overkill since the event will fire every time the mouse moves over the control. Have you tried doing this background color change in the controls `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` events? As already noted, without some code to test... it is pure speculation as to why it is not working for you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All childs must share the same method which `MouseEnter` event from parent will access, because if not, when your mouse is over childs it will raise `MouseLeave` event of parent.

This is an example:

```
public partial class Test : Form
{
    public Test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myPictureBox1.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => { AllControls_MouseEnter(); };
        myLabel1.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => { AllControls_MouseEnter(); };
        myLabel2.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => { AllControls_MouseEnter(); };
    }

    private void Panel_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AllControls_MouseEnter();
    }

    private void Panel_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AllControls_MouseLeave();
    }

    private void AllControls_MouseEnter()
    {
        Panel.BackColor = Color.Firebrick;
    }

    private void AllControls_MouseLeave()
    {
        Panel.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
}
```

Of course, `myPictureBox1`, `myLabel1` and `myLabel2` are childs of `Panel`, as you could figure it out.

Or if you have a lot of controls, you can iterate thru all `Controls` collection of parent (it is the method I would choose, instead of assigning to all controls), like this:

```
foreach (var c in Panel.Controls)
{
    ((Control)c).MouseEnter += (sender, e) => { AllControls_MouseEnter(); };
}
```

This is the demo of Test form (with and without `foreach...`):
[image]